# JDBC Response save in csv file using JSR223 Postprocessor in the script location

Tags: jdbc, groovy, jmeter, jsr223

I am trying to store my JDBC response in a CSV file with a particular path / Location on my local system. Please help me with the code below to pass my result path.

```
resultSet = vars.getObject("resultSet")
result = new StringBuilder()

def randomRow = resultSet.get(org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextInt(0,resultSet.size()))

randomRow.each { k, v -> 
    result.append("${k}").append(",")
}
result.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"))

for (Object row: resultSet ) {
    iter = row.entrySet().iterator()
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        pair = iter.next()
        result.append(pair.getValue())
        result.append(",")
    }
    result.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"))
}

org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File("foo.csv"), result.toString(), "UTF-8")
```

My script is working but it stores the values in my JMeter bin folder instead want to store a particular folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This constructor: `new File("foo.csv")` assumes that JMeter will save the output in the `foo.csv` file in its **working directory**.

If you want a "particular folder" you can specify the [full path instead of the relative path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/path.html), i.e.

`new File("c:/onefolder/anotherfolder/foo.csv")`

Also be informed that if you will run your script with 2 or more threads (virtual users) in [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) - they will start concurrently writing into the same file which will result in data corruption or loss ([race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition)) so it's better to declare the variables from the JDBC Request as [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) and go for [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-ten-jmeter-plugins#writer) instead of the JSR223 test element

Comment: already tried this method im getting some exception error and we can't directly pass our path in this case. thanks for your suggestion for the flexible file writer